# Git checkout -b feature/testbranch is automaticly renamed to Feature/testbranch. How can this behavior explained?

Tags: git, branch, repo

I'm in a new Project with existing git-repos. There is a behavior that I can't explain to myself.
I want to create a new branch feature/testbranch with git-bash for windows (v2.41.0.windows.3)

```
git checkout -b feature/testbranch
```

After I've done this, the branch is automaticly renamed to Feature/testbranch. Git doesn't tell me why. There are no hooks under .git/hooks.

```
git branch --list
```

`-> master`
`-> develop`
`-> Feature/testbranch`

If I choose another prefix-branch like bugfix. This doesnt happen.

```
git checkout -b bugfix/testbranch  
git branch --list
```

`-> master`
`-> develop`
`-> bugfix/testbranch`

It's different to if I create the branch with the following command:

```
git branch feature/testbranch
git branch --list
```

`-> master`
`-> develop`
`-> feature/testbranch`

Can somebody explain this befavior or push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're on Windows.  By default, Windows file systems behave in a case-insensitive way.  Because Git usually (but not always) stores references in the file system, there can usually be at most one of `feature/testbranch` and `Feature/testbranch` at a time.

It's likely that you already have or had a branch starting with `Feature/`, so the directory corresponding to that reference already exists.  Thus, when you create a new branch under that directory, Git reads it from the file system as `Feature/testbranch` instead of `feature/testbranch`.

You wouldn't have this problem on a non-macOS Unix system, a macOS system with a case-sensitve file system, or under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, all of which store files in a case-sensitive way.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much!